# Insert a new record if not exist and don't update if exist, laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

Should I use `create` method to insert a new record if doesn't exist and don't update the record if exist? Thanks.

Answer (score 57):

Use the `firstOrCreate` method for that:

```php
$user = User::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'John Doe']);
```

If you want to know whether the user was created or fetched, check the `wasRecentlyCreated` property:

```php
if ($user->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    // "firstOrCreate" didn't find the user in the DB, so it created it.
} else {
    // "firstOrCreate" found the user in the DB and fetched it.
}
```

Comment: how we can find out if a record is created and how we can find out if record is not created because it was already existing.

Comment: @usama -  you can check the model's `wasRecentlyCreated` property, which tells you whether the model was just created. If it was fetched from the database, `$user->wasRecentlyCreated` will be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.2 you have the `updateOrCreate` method from Builder.php, it uses the `firstOrNew` method to verify if the given attributes exists in db and update the records with the given values or create and save the new records.

The weird thing is that `updateOrCreate` doesn't appear in the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

```
/**
 * Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 */
public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    $instance = $this->firstOrNew($attributes);

    $instance->fill($values)->save();

    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: The updateOrCreate method is now in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Comment: The question was about not updating record if exists

Comment: This answers a different problem, not what OP asked..